# Convert JSON to XML in Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have parsed a JSON string in Logic Apps using the parse json connector.  How do I put the output from that step into an xml file?
One suggestion I've seen is to use "when a http request is received", but this is a trigger and I need an action.
On user voice there is a request for a parse xml function 
[here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/32403349-data-operations-parse-xml)
.  I need a workaround.
Another problem I'm having is that parse json is returning an object, but I think I need an array.

This is the schema in my parse json connector.  After parse json I'm trying to initialise a variable.  It's not accepting a type of string.

```
<code>
{
"properties": {
    "PR_ADD1": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "PR_ADD2": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "PR_ADD3": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "RLS_GROUP": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"title": "The Root Schema",
"type": "object"
}  
</code>

How do I initialize the first variable as string with the output from my 
previous parse json step?  In [this example] 
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform- 
data-operations#parse-json-action) there is only one record.  My parse 
json step has lots of records.
```

Here is some sample JSON

```
<code>
 {
 "properties": {
    "PR_ADD1": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "PR_ADD2": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "PR_ADD3": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "PR_ZONEC": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "RLS_GROUP": {
        "type": "string"
    }
 },
 "title": "The Root Schema",
 "type": "object"
 }
</code>
```

Here is my Logic APP

```
{
"definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
        "Compose_2": {
            "inputs": "@length(variables('IntermediateArray'))",
            "runAfter": {
                "Scope": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ],
                "Set_variable": [
                    "Succeeded",
                    "Skipped"
                ]
            },
            "type": "compose"
        },
        "Compose_From_HTTP2": {
            "inputs": "@body('HTTP_2')",
            "runAfter": {
                "HTTP_2": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "compose"
        },
        "HTTP_2": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "FORMAT": "payload",
                    "FROM": 0,
                    "GRIDID": "PROP",
                    "GRIDVIEW": "1",
                    "HITS": 100,
                    "ORDERBY": "PR_DATESOLD",
                    "PROFILE": [
                        {
                            "PR_NAME": "G*",
                            "PR_USER1": "GENERATED"
                        }
                    ],
                    "sessionID": "@body('Parse_JSON3')['sessionID']"
                },
                "headers": {
                    "Accept": "text/json",
                    "Content-Type": "text/json"
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "@variables('uri_DefGrid')"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Parse_JSON3": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Http"
        },
        "HTTP_Logout": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "method": "logout",
                    "sessionID": "@body('Parse_JSON3')['sessionID']"
                },
                "headers": {
                    "Accept": "text/json",
                    "Content-Type": "text/json"
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "@variables('uri_logout')"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_uri_logout": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Http"
        },
        "Initialize_Header": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "Header",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "{\"Accept\":\"text/json\",\"Content-Type\":\"text/json\"}"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_body_login": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_body_login": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "body_login",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "json(@{triggerBody()})"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_intermediateArray": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "intermediateArray",
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Compose_From_HTTP2": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_sharepointLibraryPath": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "sharepointLibraryPath",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "https://qqqonline.sharepoint.com/teams-and-projects/dev/hhh"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Compose_2": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_uri_DefGrid": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "uri_DefGrid",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "https://mh-uat.ttt-app.uk:443/qqq_uat/wrd/run/pppMHAPI.GRIDGET"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_uri_login": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_uri_login": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "uri_login",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "https://mh-uat.ttt-app.uk:443/qqq_uat/wrd/run/pppJSONSERVICE.LOGIN"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_Header": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_uri_logout": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "uri_logout",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "https://mh-uat.ttt-app.uk:443/qqq_uat/wrd/run/pppJSONSERVICE.LOGOUT"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_sharepointLibraryPath": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_variable": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "initializeArray",
                        "type": "array",
                        "value": "@outputs('Compose_From_HTTP2')"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_intermediateArray": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Parse_JSON3": {
            "inputs": {
                "content": "@triggerBody()",
                "schema": {
                    "properties": {
                        "RLS_WHERE": {
                            "$id": "#/properties/RLS_WHERE",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "contact": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "error": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "errorId": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "fullName": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "labellanguage": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "language": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "message": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "params": {
                            "properties": {
                                "WOPARTSOPT": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "WOPARTSOPT"
                            ],
                            "title": "The Params Schema",
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "role": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "sessionID": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "success": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "userEmail": {
                            "$id": "#/properties/userEmail",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "success",
                        "message",
                        "sessionID",
                        "language",
                        "labellanguage",
                        "error",
                        "errorId",
                        "fullName",
                        "role",
                        "contact",
                        "RLS_WHERE",
                        "userEmail",
                        "params"
                    ],
                    "title": "The Root Schema",
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_uri_DefGrid": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "ParseJson"
        },
        "Scope": {
            "actions": {
                "Scope_2": {
                    "actions": {
                        "Compose": {
                            "inputs": "@array(outputs('Compose_From_HTTP2'))",
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "compose"
                        },
                        "Set_variable_2": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "name": "intermediateArray",
                                "value": "@outputs('Compose')"
                            },
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Compose": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "SetVariable"
                        }
                    },
                    "runAfter": {},
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_variable": [
                    "Failed"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Scope"
        },
        "Set_variable": {
            "inputs": {
                "name": "intermediateArray",
                "value": "@outputs('Compose_From_HTTP2')"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_variable": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "SetVariable"
        }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {},
    "triggers": {
        "HTTP": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "method": "login",
                    "password": "qqq_API",
                    "username": "qqq_API"
                },
                "headers": {
                    "Accept": "text/json",
                    "Content-Type": "text/json"
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "https://mh-uat.ttt-app.uk:443/qqq_uat/wrd/run/pppJSONSERVICE.LOGIN"
            },
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 4
            },
            "type": "Http"
        }
    }
},
"parameters": {}
}
```

[image: Here is my Parse Json step.]

[image: Here is the following Compose step]

The parse json screenshot showed the top of the schema.  Here is the bottom.

```
"RLS_GROUP": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"title": "The Root Schema",
"type": "object"
}
```

When I generate the schema from sample output in parse json I get error messages like this.  I think that when integer fields have not value they are coming back with two double quotes to denote empty rather than null.  Also, I think the schema is basing itself on the first record which could have data.  Subsequent records may not.  Conversely the first record may not have data for a particular field, but subsequent records will have data for that field.

```
"message": "Invalid type. Expected Integer but got String.",
"lineNumber": 0,
"linePosition": 0,
"path": "Payload[1].PR_RENT",
"value": "",
"schemaId": "#/properties/Payload/items/properties/PR_RENT",
"errorType": "type",
"childErrors": []
},
{
"message": "Invalid type. Expected String but got Integer.",
"lineNumber": 0,
"linePosition": 0,
"path": "Payload[3].PR_ID",
"value": 1363,
"schemaId": "#/properties/Payload/items/properties/PR_ID",
"errorType": "type",
"childErrors": []
},
{
"message": "Invalid type. Expected String but got Integer.",
"lineNumber": 0,
"linePosition": 0,
"path": "Payload[3].PR_USER8",
"value": 0,
"schemaId": "#/properties/Payload/items/properties/PR_USER8",
"errorType": "type",
"childErrors": []
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** For your first question, we can use xml() method in logic app to do the convert. As I don't know your json data(you mentioned it is a json string in your question), so I assuming that your data is like the data below:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "city": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tom",
    "city": "DEF"
  }
]
```

Then we can convert it by following the steps in the screenshot below:
[image]

The expression in the screenshot is:

```
xml(json(concat('{"root":{"person":', variables('test'), '}}')))
```

After that, we can get the xml data at last:

```
<root><person><name>Mike</name><city>ABC</city></person><person><name>Tom</name><city>DEF</city></person></root>
```

**2.** For your second question about return object or array, it depends on the data you input to the "Parse JSON" action.

If you input the data which is array shown as the screenshot below
[image]

We will get a array return from the "Parse JSON" action
[image]

If you input the data which is object shown as the screenshot below
[image]

We will get an object return from the "Parse JSON" action
[image]

Hope it would be helpful to your problems~

**Update:**

According to your comments, you want to choose some of the fields from the "Parse JSON" and then convert it to xml. I post an example below for your reference:

I assume that your data is like this：

```
{
    "PR_ADD1": "aaa",
    "PR_ADD2": "bbb",
    "PR_ADD3": "ccc",
    "PR_ZONEC": "ddd",
    "RLS_GROUP": "eee"
}
```

And in after parse json, I assume you don't want the field "PR_ZONEC" and keep other four fields, and convert them to xml. So please refer to my logic app:

1. I do the "Parse JSON" action.
   [image]
2. Then, use "Compose" action, and in "Compose" action I remove the field "PR_ZONEC", keep the other four fields.
   [image]
3. At last, convert it to xml.
   [image]

The expression is

```
xml(json(concat('{"root":', string(outputs('Compose')), '}')))
```

4. After these steps, I got the result I want.
   [image]

The whole of the xml is

```
<root>
<PR_ADD1>aaa</PR_ADD1>
<PR_ADD2>bbb</PR_ADD2>
<PR_ADD3>ccc</PR_ADD3>
<RLS_GROUP>eee</RLS_GROUP>
</root>
```

Comment: I used the body in the http call preceding the parse json step.

Comment: Hi @AlHal Sorry for the delay, but I'm not so clear about your new question. Your question is "How do I initialize the first variable as string with the output from my 
previous parse json step", per my understanding you just need to create a "Initialize variable" action and set the type as "string" and then choose the first property from the "Parse JSON" and set it to the value box of the "Initialize variable" action. Maybe I misunderstand your question, so could you please provide some more details (such as the screenshots of your logic app) ? I will try my best to help you on it. Thanks.

Comment: I have a Parse JSON action.  This gives lots of fields.  I want to select a certain number of fields and filter the output for a certain number of rows.  I start my select action after parse json, but the expression builder doesn't show me any variables from the previous parse json step.  Parse JSON creates an object, but the Select action needs an array.

Comment: Hi @AlHal Could you please show a sample of your json data, you can add the sample to the question area. And please show a sample what you want at last.

Comment: @AlHal According to your question description, if your json data is an object with some fields and you just want to select some fields from it. Why not use [Compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action) action to do it, I think we don't need to use "Select" action. You can type the fields' name in the "input" box of "Compose" action and use the fields from the "Parse JSON" action. If it can't meet your requirements, please share more details of your requirements, I will try to help you.

Comment: After the parse json step I initialise a string variable called IntermediateOutput which is from the compose function.  Then I try to convert to xml using this function to initialise an object.

@{xml(json(concat('{"root":{"payload":', variables('IntermediateOutput'), '}}')))}
I get this error message.
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Initialize_OutputXML' inputs at line '1' and column '2783': 'The template language function 'json' parameter is not valid.

Comment: Rest of error message.  The provided value '{"root":{"payload":}}' cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: }. Path 'root.payload', line 1, position 19.'.

Comment: In the Compose method I added some outputs from the parse json step.  When I run it the inputs to the compose function come up as empty.  For example @{body('Parse_JSON4')?['PR_ADD1']}@{body('Parse_JSON4')?['PR_SNAM']}@{body('Parse_JSON4')?['PR_OWN']}.  My aim is to produce an xml file from this JSON output.  I only want certain records and certain fields eg where PR_NAM has a particular value.

Comment: Hi @AlHal, I added an "Update" at the end of my answer with an example of my logic app. Please refer to it.

Comment: If I hard code some values into Parse JSON the compose method works.  However, I want the input for my parse json step to be the output from the previous http request.  If I do that, all the values in the compose step are null even though the output has values for those fields.

Comment: @AlHal Could you please provide the screenshots of your "Parse JSON" and "Compose"

Comment: Hi @AlHal, you need to modify your source data. You need to add double quotes for each field, regardless of whether it has data or not. If it is an integer(eg 10). I think the problem is caused by the format of your source data but not the "Parse JSON", so the only way is standardize your data format.

Comment: The data is coming from an http request.  How do I modify it?
Also, what about replacing two double quotes with a null value if that's possible?

Comment: @AlHal Maybe you can have a try. In my opinion, if the integer fields have not value, could you please replace it with 0 or -1 or some other specific number but not just response "" ?

Comment: Presumably, I need to add something between the http request and the parse json actions.  Would you be able to give an idea of what that should be?  I can the use that action to change blank values to null, zero or one.  Would you like me to add this as a new question?

Comment: @AlHal The best solution is change the format at the source of the data, but if you have to do this change between http request and parse json action, I think you can try to use [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#replace) method to replace all of the "" with 0 or 1. Before replace it, you'd better convert the response of http request to string with [string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#string) method.

Comment: I think the split function would suit me better.  If I have more problems I will raise another question.  Thanks very much for your help.